# How can I make FireFox NOT select the RadioButton when an associated TextBox gets clicked?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox

I have a `TextBox` that is inside of a `RadioButton's` label. In FireFox (v8.0.1), when you click this TextBox it changes focus on MouseUp to the RadioButton, which means the TextBox is no longer selected.

This is giving FireFox users the illusion that the TextBox cannot get selected, even though you can select it if you tab to it or double-click it.

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="PaymentAmount" ID="rbAmount_Other" />
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rbAmount_Other">
    Some Text
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherAmount" CssClass="money-text" />
    Some other Text
</asp:Label>
```

[image]

I have tried using jQuery to stop this behavior, but am not having any luck because the RadioButton's `.changed()` and `.focus()` don't get fired when the TextBox gets selected, even though the RadioButton gets selected.

How can I keep the existing behavior of highlighting or selecting the RadioButton when the text or TextBox gets hovered over or clicked, but make the TextBox keep it's focus when it gets selected?

**Edit**

HTML output as requested:

```
<input id="ctl00_cphPageContent_rbAmount_Other" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphPageContent$PaymentAmount" value="rbAmount_Other" />
<label for="ctl00_cphPageContent_rbAmount_Other">
    <label>Pay other amount</label>
    <input name="ctl00$cphPageContent$txtOtherAmount" type="text" id="ctl00_cphPageContent_txtOtherAmount" class="money-text" />
    <div class="align-with-radiobutton small-text">
        The minimum amount for web payments is
        <span id="ctl00_cphPageContent_lblMinPayment">$20.00</span>. If you are looking to pay a lower
        amount, please <a href="Contact.aspx">contact us</a> and speak with a representative.
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Your HTML output would be much more helpful than your .NET source code. This all happens on the client, so show the client code.

Comment: Have you tried preventing the default behavior of the radio button's .click() event? I would think that would be the event fired when you click the label (or anything inside the label) of the radio button.

Comment: @itsmequinn Yes I did try `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, but neither worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with a `.focus()` event on the `RadioButton` to set focus to the `TextBox`, and a `.focus()` event on the `TextBox` to select the `RadioButton`

It now works correctly for both keyboard and mouse navigation

```
$('#<%= txtOtherAmount.ClientId %>').focus(function () {
    $('#<%= rbAmount_Other.ClientId %>').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#<%= rbAmount_Other.ClientId %>').focus(function () {
    $('#<%= txtOtherAmount.ClientId %>').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "for" attribute in the first label:

```
<input id="ctl00_cphPageContent_rbAmount_Other" type="radio" name="ctl00$cphPageContent$PaymentAmount" value="rbAmount_Other" />
<label for=""><label for="ctl00_cphPageContent_rbAmount_Other">Pay other amount</label><input name="ctl00$cphPageContent$txtOtherAmount" type="text" id="ctl00_cphPageContent_txtOtherAmount" class="money-text" AssociatedControlId="txtOtherAmount" />
    <div class="align-with-radiobutton small-text">
        The minimum amount for web payments is
        <span id="ctl00_cphPageContent_lblMinPayment">$20.00</span>. If you are looking to pay a lower
        amount, please <a href="Contact.aspx">contact us</a> and speak with a representative.
    </div>
</label>
```

I don't think nesting labels is a good idea.

Comment: But then I lose the default behavior of the RadioButton getting highlighted or selected when the Text or Textbox is hovered over or clicked

Comment: Then add an onclick event to the textbox to check the radio button. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I found a solution that works and posted it as an answer. I agree that nesting labels is a bad idea, but I'm not really sure how else to get what I want without a lot of extra work, and since this works I am going with it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep behavior of selecting or highlighting radio button, use something like that:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ctl00_cphPageContent_txtOtherAmount").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ctl00_cphPageContent_rbAmount_Other").click();
    });
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ympSk/1/)

Comment: That only works for mouse clicks, not keyboard events such as tabbing to the control. Also, I tried both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` and neither work.